# Getting Formtastic::UnknownInputError when displaying HStore in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

How can I display textarea for editing an hstore field in ActiveAdmin?

At the moment I'm getting an error when I want to open the edit form:

```
Formtastic::UnknownInputError
Unable to find input class for hstore
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 8):

This might help

```
  class HstoreInput < Formtastic::Inputs::TextInput

  end
```

Put this class to initializers or autoload path.

Other option is render it with

> `as: :text`

option